# Assigning new table from a variable

Tags: r, function, assign

I want to add a new column to an existing table in a part of a function in R. (With an intention for adding more arguments to this function in the future) The problem is that in the first argument of the assign() call I'd need the "table" variable as a character (to give me the value: "MB_binvar" in this case).

```
binner <- function(table, newcol) {
  table$blankcol <- NA
  table <- rename(table, c("blankcol" = newcol))
  assign("table", table, envir=.GlobalEnv)
}

binner(table = MB_binvar, newcol = "test")
```

Any ideas...?

Comment: Don't use `assign`. Try `binner <- function(table, newcol) {table[newcol] <- NA ; table}` for instance. This will work for any amount of new columns. Try `binner(table = mtcars, newcol = paste0("test", 1:3))` for instance.

Comment: @sandoronodi why not simply return a new table? do you really want a function to change existing table? I think you could easily do with `MB_binvar=binner(table = MB_binvar, newcol = "test")`

Comment: Thank you! All you've written worked fine.